# second order differential equation with Green's function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

I need to solve following differential equation

\begin{eqnarray}
y''(x) - k = \delta(x-x_0)
\end{eqnarray}

subject to conditions:
\begin{eqnarray}
y(x=-a) = 0 \\
y(x=b) = p
\end{eqnarray}

Is it possible to solve the equation using Green's function?
I tried as follows:
solution of the homogeneous equation
\begin{eqnarray}
y''(x) - k = 0
\end{eqnarray}

is $y(x) = k/2x^2 + bx + c$

but in this case I am not able to split $y(x)$ into two liner independent functions
to use boundary conditions. How can I proceed?

**EDIT**

Following  Silynn's comment This seems to be the solution:
\begin{eqnarray}
y(x) &=& (x-x_0)\theta(x-x_0) + \frac{k}{2}x^2 + a_1x + a_2 \\
 y'(x) &=& (x-x_0)\delta(x-x_0) + \theta(x-x_0)+ kx + a_1 \\
y''(x) &=& \delta(x-x_0)+ k \\
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: Green's functions aren't really necessary here, have you tried writing it as $y''(x)=\delta(x-x_0)+k$ and integrating twice?

Comment: @Silynn, yes I tried that one. Heaviside step function's differentiation gives delta function. But do not know integration of Heaviside function.

Comment: You can use the property $\int^x_a f(x) H(x-x_0) \, \mathrm{d} x = (F(x) - F(x_0))H(x-x_0) $. If you are interested in how to solve this problem using Green's function let me know.

Comment: @Silynn, I think I have arrived at solution following your comment. If you can make it as answer I can mark it as the correct one.

Comment: @Dmoreno, I think I need your expertise in here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/902934/solution-of-yx-k-deltax-x-0y