# Solution of $y''(x) -k = \delta(x-x_0)y(x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

I need to solve following differential equation
$y''(x) -k = y\delta(x-x_0)$

subject to boundary conditions

\begin{eqnarray}
y(x=-a) = 0 \\
y(x=b) = p
\end{eqnarray}

I am not sure if it is possible to solve at all. I got solution for 
a similar [problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/902888/second-order-differential-equation-with-greens-function).

Can anyone suggest any way for moving ahead?

**EDIT** 
Physical background:

Non dimensional differential equation for Poiseuille flow, is $$y''(x) = k $$ Where $y(x)$ is transverse velocity and $k$ contains information of viscosity, gravity.

to account for additional friction between wall and fluid velocity a term proportional to velocity and in the vicinity of wall is added(in the limit a $\delta$ function) so that differential equation is 
$$y''(x) -k = \delta(x-x_0)y(x)$$

Comment: @hjpotter92, there is difference in the right hand side of the two questions.

Comment: Can you explain to us if this problem has a physical background behind? I feel I'm not able to solve this because of the $y \, \delta(x-x_0)$ term which make the ODE quite complicated.

Comment: @Dmoreno, I have added the physical background.

Comment: I see now but @Winther has been faster than me. Are you allowed to proceed numerically? In the other hand, I'm interested in the way you derived the non-dimensional equation for the Hagen-Poiseuille flow. If the NS equation for this particular case is reduced to: $$ u_y \frac{\partial u_x}{\partial y} = p_g + \nu \frac{\partial^2 u_x}{\partial y^2},$$ where I have assumed that the flow is incompressible, $\partial_x = 0$ and $p_g$ is a fixed pressure gradient, then I have assumed you have neglected convection and have added an 'extra' friction term. What is the physical meaning of this term?

Comment: @Dmoreno, After what you have derived we assume $u_y =0$(i.e. there is no flow in the direction perpendicular to gravity which follows by symmetry) and arrive at equation in the question. While solving Usual NS equations we specify value of velocity at the boundary. Here friction force is added to make sure velocity in the vicinity of wall be made gradually zero. Velocity profile can be then expected to be not parabolic nearby wall.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solve the equation seperately for $x>x_0$ and $x<x_0$.

For $x<x_0$ we have $$y'' - k =0 \to y = y_1(x) = \frac{k}{2}x^2 + Ax + B$$

For $x>x_0$ we have $$y'' - k =0 \to y = y_2(x) = \frac{k}{2}x^2 + Cx + D$$

First apply the boundary conditions (I assume $x_0 \in (-a,b)$). This gives the equations

$$y_1(-a) = 0$$
$$y_2(b) = p$$

Now apply continuity for $y$ and $y'$ at $x=x_0$ to determine the unknown constants in the expressions above. This gives the two equations

$$y_1(x_0) = y_2(x_0)$$
$$y_1'(x_0) = y_2'(x_0)$$

The four equations above are just enough to specify the four constants $A,B,C,D$ in the solution.

${\bf EDIT}$: I don't think we can assume $y'$ being continious across the gap. To determine the final equation we can integrate the equation over $x=x_0$ to find

$$0 \equiv \lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\int_{x_0-\epsilon}^{x_0+\epsilon}y''(x) - k - y\delta(x-x_0) dx = \lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\left[y'(x) - kx\right]_{x-\epsilon}^{x+\epsilon} + y(x_0) = y_2'(x_0) - y_1'(x_0) - y(x_0)$$

Where $y(x_0) = y_1(x_0) = y_2(x_0)$. Thus $y_2'(x_0) - y_1'(x_0) - y(x_0) = 0$ should be the second equations you need.

To speed up the algebra it can be useful to write the solutions as $y_1(x) = \frac{k}{2}(x+a)^2 + A(x+a) + B$ and $y_2(x) = \frac{k}{2}(x-b)^2 + C(x-b) + D$ instead. Then applying the boundary conditions gives the simple equations $y_1(-a) = B = 0$ and $y_2(b) = D = p$.

Comment: @Winter, Thanks a lot for the answer..!!

Comment: @alekhine Wait a bit. I think I made a small mistake: I don't think we can assume $y'$ continious across $x = x_0$. We can however use the normal Greens method trick by integrating the equation across $x=x_0$ to get the second equation. Have edited the answer.

Comment: This way if you change $y\delta(x-x_0)$ to, say, $y^2\delta(x-x_0)$ the condition changes to $y_2' - y_1' - y^2 = 0$.

Comment: yes, I understood this when I carefully read the boundary conditions. Thanks again for the explanation.